# How to create route that search by value?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, routes

I have a recipe app with several routes (get, getById, post, delete, etc).

So far it hasn't been difficult to implement them, since, for example, a get route would be like this:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Recipe> getAllRecipe() {
     return recipesRepository.findAll();
}
```

Or by id:

Repository:

```
public interface RecipesRepository extends MongoRepository<Recipe, String> {
    Recipe findBy_id(String _id);
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Recipe getRecipeById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return recipesRepository.findBy_id(id);
}
```

I want to make a search screen in my app, so when you write something (like "straw") I get all results that contain the word "straw" in my database (like strawberry ice cream, strawberry milkshake...) in the name field (my model has a field called name).

My knowledge in Java isnt by any means good, so I'm lost here, so far I have a route that gets all results using "name", but I need it to search anything that contains that value, not only if you put the exact value (like if I put "Stew", it gives me "Stew" result if it exists, but I need to get every result that have the word "Stew" in their name). If it helps, this is the code for that:

Repository:

```
public interface RecipesRepository extends MongoRepository<Recipe, String> {
    Recipe findBy_id(String _id);
    Recipe findByName(String name);
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recipe/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Recipe getRecipeByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
    return recipesRepository.findByName(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use smth like this one :

```
public interface RecipesRepository extends MongoRepository<Recipe, String> {
{ 
 public List<Recipe> findByNameLike(String name);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Works like wonders, it was what I needed. One more thing, my route is "/recipe/{name}" but seems that is case sensitive, is there anyway to make it NOT case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

About the case sensitive problem, you can add keywords, like this:

```
public interface RecipesRepository extends MongoRepository<Recipe, String> {
{ 
 public List<Recipe> findByNameLikeIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

Comment: Yep! Just what I needed, thinking it would be something harder but was just adding "Like" and  "IgnoreCase"!